# Angular2 BrowserDomAdapter ':eq(0)' selector giving an error

Tags: angular

I am converting my jQuery to Angular2

So I have such jQuery selector `$('.mdl-tabs__tab:eq(1)').addClass('active');` and it is working fine which analogue in Angular2 `dom.addClass(dom.query('.mdl-tabs__tab:eq(0)'), 'active');`

which is giving me an error:

***ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.mdl-tabs__tab:eq(0)' is not a valid selector.***

any thought why and how to fix?

Answer (score -1):

`eq()` is pure jQuery. Angular2 is not jQuery

See for example `eq(X)` in https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/